# #xslt #C++ Excel Suddenly Crashing on Print Preview

Tags: excel, printing, crash

Excel Suddenly Crashing on Print Preview, If we see log we found 
Excel Crashing: Faulting module name: mso20win32client.dll

If you are generating or your generated excel(.xlsx, .xsl) from openxml generated then you need to add below syntax while transforming using xslt.

this happens because of printer windows needs some window for printing, If we not providing some window before view that time crash on printing.Provide some window dimension for printer
add this syntax **before sheetview**

Answer (score 0):

try below syntax this may fix excel crash while print preview

{`<bookViews><workbookView xWindow="120" yWindow="90" windowWidth="28515" windowHeight="14370" /></bookViews><sheets><sheet name="Sheet1" sheetId="1" r:id="rId1"/></sheets>`}